# Laravel send mail and pass User email

Tags: php, laravel, email

I would like to send a register confirmation mail to my user. Everything works but how can I fill in the mail address dynamic from my user? something like this does not work:   $message->to($user->email);

```
$user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->name = $name;
        $user->password =$password;

        $user->save();

        $name = $user->name;
        $email = $user->email;

        Mail::send('email.registerMail', ['name'=>$name, 'email'=> $email], function ($message) {
            $message->from('info@abc.de', 'abc');

            $message->to($user->email);
        });

        return redirect()->route('success');

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mail::send('email.registerMail', ['name'=>$name, 'email'=> $email], function ($message) use ($email) {
        $message->from('info@abc.de', 'abc');

        $message->to($email);
    });
```

Notice the function(..) use ($email) and $message->to($email).
You have to use 'use' because $email is only defined in the parent scope.